# Center Webpage with Divs

Tags: html, web

Let me preface this question with the warning that I'm a self-taught (amateur) web developer (and not a very good one).  I've been trying for a long time to find an effective way of centering web pages using AP Divs.  I've tried setting "margin: 0 auto;" and I've tried setting "margin-left: auto;".  Both work for that one div.  But I then have to use that as a wrapper to design within, so when I put more divs inside that, they don't center.

I may be completely approaching this wrong; if so, please correct me.  Code (not working) for a basic version of what I want to do is below.  If you run that code, if I were to place, say, an image in apDiv1, it would scale to the page size fine; but the text in apDiv2 does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:24px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 47px;
    top: 29px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="apDiv1">
  <div id="apDiv2">Hello</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are putting DIVs inside of DIVs, then you likely don't want to be using absolute positioning in the first place.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do exactly? The CSS for `#apDiv1` will center it. So do you want to center the divs inside that?

Comment: I'm trying to make a webpage.  I want the whole page to be in the center of the browser.  I had hoped that I would center one div, then put my other divs inside of that, allowing me to design the site by moving divs around within the wrapper div.  That doesn't seem to be working, and I have a feeling my entire approach is off...

Comment: "then put my other divs inside of that" and do what with them? "Move them around" is as vague as the original question

Comment: @gmaster I don't think you want absolute positioning here. Typically, to center a page, you give a wrapper div a width and `margins: auto` and it centers itself.

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/RdscG/2/)**

Ok after some guessing and poking I think you mean that you want to absolutely position the elements inside the center-aligned wrapper.

`position: absolute` will be absolute to the page UNLESS the parent has `position: relative`.

```
#apDiv1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I lose any ability to move the div inside the other div around to create a design... I don't want the inner div "centered" necessarily, I just want it to scale to the window size along with the rest of the page.

Comment: @gmaster absolute positioning isn't usually good for page layout due to the inflexibility you are discovering when browsers change sizes. It's useful, but more as a seasoning rather than a main ingredient. Look more in to relative positioning and creative use of margins and padding.

Answer (score 0):

I can center a div inside another div just fine using `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`:

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xjKhT/**

Answer (score 0):

In my own opinion, it is not good to use appdivs(coz it depends on how you positioned it on the design). You can do it(centering stuffs) on your own, check this:

[Centering(Simple Sample)](http://jsfiddle.net/Vainglory07/46FJr/)

```
<style>
#header {
margin:auto;
width:600px;
background:#000;
padding:5px;
}
#title {
width:50px;
margin:auto;
background:#CCC;
padding:5px;
}
</style>

<div id="header">
   <div id="title">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Custom AppDivs adds extra styles which is not really necessary:)